# KeyError with pytube module

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

How do I fix this -

```
yt = YouTube(url)
for i in stream_data[key].split(',')
KeyError: 'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'
```

The 'key' is from the pytube module and so is everything else apart from the first line `yt = YouTube(url)`

This is a know problem with the module but I cannot find any solutions, only complaints. I need to know how to fix the issue on a Windows PC.

Comment: what is "key"? where is it coming from? Please post the full code required to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I'm not sure why, but force reinstalling the module fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

These Error is occurred due to `mixins.py` present in site-packages of `pytube`

You have to do this -

```
pip install pytube3
```

And then run the program again.

I had the same error and this worked for me as pytube had made some changes in their package.

Comment: it does not work for me. do you have any idea by now?.thanks